# High current buck converter

Tags: buck

I am looking for a solution to step-down the 12V 82A from a server power supply to charge a 3S2P supercapacitor to 8.1V. Not sure which buck converter to go or if there are any specific limitation to them. Would a [LTC3824](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3824fh.pdf). Based on the datsheet I calculated 198nH at 90A but can't seem to find a suitable inductor. Where am going wrong?

Comment: You will run into problems above 20 A, which is usually where multiphase buck converters come into the picture to go around that. Try LTC7871 or parallel multiple ~20 A buck converters. The lack of off the shelf inductors available reflects that.

Comment: Thanks. The LTC7871 is a bit beyond my expertise i'd rather do couple in parallel, How did you determine the current limit ?

Comment: Several ways. Empirical testing and search. The number of commerically available inductors available drops significantly after 20 A, as well as integrated regulators available, or they become multiphase. Look at motherboards VRMs too, they are usually around 15-25 A per phase.

Comment: Forgot to mention the voltage of the supercapacitors, i've edited my question to show 8.1V. These VRMs or Desktop power supplies can't supply enormous current. Hence i chose to go with server power supplies.

Comment: What about voltage divider if you are not charging it regularly. Which supercapacitor are you using btw?

Comment: Why not charge it more slowly and avoid the high current?

Comment: This is for a spot welder project using Maxwell BCAP0360 P270 S18. Resistor divider at 80A ? The caps need to be full at all times. A weld will drop the voltage from 8 to 6V.

Comment: What determines the current limit on these ICs. @winny said 20A is max they can handle but where does it mention ? When using multiple of these do the pins of each other connect one another like in a Master/Slave configuration ?

Comment: Sort of. Most of them in single channel configuration tops out at around 20 A. I’m sure you can find examples which breaks this “rule”. The master-slave you are looking for is _interleaving_, like the LTC7871. There are alternatives to this. If you don’t care about inductor size, you just need a current limit for each to create a fold back loop. Any CCCV buck should do.